# Use speaker with microphone and avoid Loopback/ Feedback

Tags: audio, nvidia-graphics-card, microphone, speakers

Currently, I use AKG 72 headphones, but continuous use of headphones is causing discomfort. is there any way to use the external speaker and avoid loopback/ feedback, so that I can invest in the speaker? My current input device is a Deity S-mic 2 connected to an SSL2 audio interface, that is fed to Nvidia Broadcast powered by RTX 2060 super. I use my setup for Google meet calls

Answer (score 0):

Some devices are available, they are often named "anti Larsen" or so. I'm not an expert in this matter, but I remember that one of the used solutions is to shift the spectrum of one of the signals by a few Hertz.